# How do I use Bootstrap columns inside a list item?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Consider the following markup with Boostrap 3:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Row 1, col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Row 1, col 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Why does the text not align with the "1." from the `<ol>`? See http://jsfiddle.net/R2tXU/ as an example...

Also, would it be valid to put the `class="row"` right on the `<li>`?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm stumped!  I put the row on an `li` inside a `ul` and I didn't see any problems in my code, but with the `ol` the numbers sure do get all messed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, I'm a little late responding here... However, using valid markup is important and therefore I think it's worth mentioning alternative solutions...

### Option 1

Using a little HTML and CSS, you could set the `value` on each `li` ([ [Valid HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) ]):

[ [JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sv900o6x/) ]

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li class="col-xs-6" value="1">Row 1, col 1</li>
    <li class="col-xs-6">Row 1, col 2</li>
    <li class="col-xs-6" value="2">Row 2, col 1</li>
    <li class="col-xs-6">Row 2, col 2</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol li:nth-child(2n+0) {
    list-style: none;
}
```

### Option 2

However, if you're going for a purely CSS approach, this is probably the best option...

[ [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sv900o6x/1/) ]

HTML

```
<ol>
    <li class="col-xs-6">Row 1, col 1</li>
    <li class="col-xs-6">Row 1, col 2</li>
    <li class="col-xs-6">Row 2, col 1</li>
    <li class="col-xs-6">Row 2, col 2</li>
</ol>
```

CSS

```
ol {
    counter-reset: index;
}

ol li:nth-child(2n+0) {
    counter-increment: index;
    list-style: none;
}

ol li:nth-child(2n+0):before {
    content: counter(index) ".";
}

ol li:nth-child(2n+0):before {
    content: "";
}
```

However, do keep in mind [ [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters) ].

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make this work with portlets?  The background color doesn't fill to the bottom of the portlet when using this method.

Edit:  Never mind, just wrap it in a DIV with `row` class.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I fixed it. No other additional styles, only Bootstrap classes.

You just need to add these class to `row` div `d-inline-flex w-100`

```
 <ol>
    <li>
        <div class="row d-inline-flex w-100 ml-2">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Row 1, col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Row 1, col 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="row d-inline-flex w-100 ml-2">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Row 2, col 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                Row 2, col 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/R2tXU/82/)