# Bootstrap grid incorrect width

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm new in Boostrap and I'm in a place where I'm not able to move from... I tried many things, checking Boostrap docs, etc., but I need to help.

I have the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
#wrapper {background: yellow; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }
.info {background: blue;}
#side {background: red}
#data {background: orange;}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <p id="breadcrumbs">
                Breadcrumbs
            </p>

            <h1>...</h1>
            <p class="info">
                Info<br>info<br>
            </p>

            <div class="row">
                <section id="side" class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    ...
                </section>

                <section class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <ul id="data" class="row gx-5">
                            <li class="col-4">...</li>
                            <li class="col-4">...</li>
                            <li class="col-4">...</li>
                            <li class="col-4">...</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is that #breadcrumbs, h1, .info has any width (max-width of their wrapper, let's say 1600px), but .row is bigger. It has negative left/right margin taken from _grid.scss:6.

When I set background color to #side element, it goes visually outside the grid.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

I tried to check Bootstrap manual, change the bootstrap class names, etc.
I expect the nested .row will have width 100% of its parent.

I attach image/screenshot, how it looks. At the top is visible p.info (its boundaries), at the bottom .row with red background, which is going outside the .info and their parent.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHM5A.png)

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3fxnthp/

Comment: `<div class="col-12 p-0">` - remove `p-0`?

Comment: No, it was one of my attemps, do nothing (yes, add padding, but the red box is still bigger)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem

Comment: @imhvost: for example, https://jsfiddle.net/brjcafLo/1/ If `.p-0` is removed, there is also problem:

Comment: `.col`, `.row` - this is for the grid. You don't need to insert them everywhere. Style elements inside `.col`: [https://jsfiddle.net/a82rwj5o/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/a82rwj5o/2/)

Comment: @imhvost: it was just due to code simplicity - there are another .col-* inside, check updated jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/brjcafLo/2/ There are 2 elements in a row above #data (sort data form), and then #data has another .col-* elements (LI in 3/4 in a row).

Comment: @imhvost: i didn't notice you made a change: updated fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/e3fxnthp/

Comment: Note these when using Bootstrap grid.  1. Use `div` tag for `row` and `col` classes.  2.  Do not add any custom styles (or other classes to adjust width, padding, margin) to `row` or `col`  divs. 3. All immediate children of a `row` MUST have a `col-*` class

Comment: @kiranvj: Thanks for you comment. "All immediate children of a row MUST have a col-* class" I think I have it. Would be please so kind and update my Fiddle? The last section (red/orange) is as you write and is broken. Sorry, I'm lost in it... And if .row/col classes for divs only, how I can make list of items where I want 4 in a row on desktop, 3 in tablets, 2 in phones? Here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961623/how-do-i-use-bootstrap-columns-inside-a-list-item, the accepted answer has .col-* classes on LI too.

Comment: Check this updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dun23jms/2/    I have added a `container` class ([docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/)) and rearranged some elements. Check if this works for you.

Comment: @kiranvj: yeah, it looks great. Added .container (-fluid in my case) is what I looked for. Many thanks.

Comment: Good that it worked. I have added it as an answer, maybe it will be helpful to others with similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. Wrapped `.container` class ([docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/)) for `.row` element and rearranged some elements.

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are required when using our default grid system.

```css
#wrapper {background: yellow; max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }
.info {background: blue;}
#side {background: red}
#data {background: orange;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <p id="breadcrumbs">
        Breadcrumbs
      </p>

      <h1>...</h1>
      <p class="info">
        Info<br>info<br>
      </p>
      <div class="container">


        <div class="row">
          <section id="side" class="col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            ...
          </section>

          <section class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-4">
                col 4
              </div>
              <div class="col-8">
                col 8
              </div>

            </div>
            <ul id="data" class="row">
              <li class="col-4">...</li>
              <li class="col-4">...</li>
              <li class="col-4">...</li>
              <li class="col-4">...</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe one more question, why there is no gap between red/orange section? It should be by default, without adding any class to all elements, shouldn't be?

Comment: @Roman That is because red/orange sections (elements with `.row` class) are not wrapped in `.container` class. Its affects spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the #side element to a div element. div element inline-block element , witch means they only takes up as much space as they need.

...

Comment: No. section and div are both block elements.

Comment: When you use the <section> tag  bootstrap add the extra padding property to the section element.  when you use the <div> tag Bootstrap does not apply any  styling rule to the element  by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).